# How to observe transition pathway of a stochastic matrix?

Tags: matrix, code-request

Given a stochastic matrix, `m`, I like to observe the transition path converging to the limiting distribution.

```
ClearAll[m];
m = {{0.2, 0, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}};
MatrixPower[m, 5]
```

How can I use `StepMonitor :> Print[m]` or a similar code to keep records of iterated matrices? My purpose is to observe the transition path for a particular element in matrix `m`, say `m[[2,2]]` or `m[[3,1]]`. For simple matrices with small matrix power, the iteration can be done manually as well. I have a large stochastic matrix to study.

Ideal answer to my question should generate a list of matrix elements, like `m[[3,1]]`, associated with matrix 5 iterations so that I can plot the data for visual inspection.

Comment: `k=5; {i,j} ={3,2}; (MatrixPower[m, #] & /@ Range[k])[[All, i, j]]`?

Comment: @kglr: Your code produces `{0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}` for me. Did you pay your attention to my answer to the question?

Comment: @user64494 user kglr took the wrong indices `i=3,j=2`

Comment: Thank you Ulrich. @user64494, the comment is just a simple variation on your answer (where we compute a list of matrix powers (`mplist=MatrixPower[m, #]&/@Range[k]` or `mplist=Table[MatrixPower[m,i], {i,k}]`) once, and get the path of entry  any desired entry `{i,j}` of `m` using `mplist[[All,i,j]]`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `m` provided you can visualize progressive change in matrix entries:

```
res = NestList[m . # &, m, 20];
f[i_, j_] := res[[All, i, j]]
Grid[Table[
  ListPlot[f[i, j], PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 1}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotLabel -> mat[i, j]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]]
```

[image]

You can use [`DiscreteMarkovProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html) to get the limit transition matrix, e.g.:

```
dm = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 1, 1}/3,m];
MarkovProcessProperties[dm, "LimitTransitionMatrix"]
```

yields: {{0.384615, 0, 0.615385}, {0.384615, 0, 0.615385}, {0.384615, 0,
0.615385}}

You can use[`RandomFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomFunction.html) if you want to simulate paths and do statistics etc.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follows.

```
m = {{0.2, 0, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}};
Table[MatrixPower[m, j][[2, 3]], {j, 1, 20}]
```

> `{0.6, 0.56, 0.614, 0.6104, 0.61526, 0.614936, 0.615373, 0.615344, 0.615384, 0.615381, 0.615385, 0.615384, 0.615385, 0.615385, 0.615385,  0.615385, 0.615385, 0.615385, 0.615385, 0.615385}`

Answer (score 3):

To extend this a bit, you can also use Animate with MatrixPlot to visualize the evolution of the matrix:

```
Clear["`*"];
m = {{0.2, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.2}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1}, {0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.1}};
mPower = Table[MatrixPower[m, z], {z, 1, 5}];
Animate[MatrixPlot[mPower[[c, All, All]], ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"], {c, 1, 5, 1}]
```

[image]

And then you can plot a location at any point:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[mPower[[v, 2, 3]], {v, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Something to adjust in your code since all the elements of `MatrixPower[m, z]` are less than or equal to 1. In view of it your `ListLinePlot` is not correct.

Comment: @user64494 MatrixProduct is perfoming a dot product of the matrices, not applying the power to each element in the matrix.  The additive terms from the products eventually rise over 1.

Comment: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) for info.

Comment: @user64494 - Thanks for the pointer!  My problem was that in my example matrix, the row probabilities added up to more than one.  The original example is a right stochastic matrix where the rows add to one.

Answer (score 3):

A natural way of building up the matrix power is by repeated application of the matrix product using [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html): Starting from the zero'th power, which is the 3×3 unit matrix ([`IdentityMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IdentityMatrix.html)),

```
m = {{0.2, 0, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}};

NestList[m . # &, IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[m]], 5]
(*    {{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
       {{0.2, 0., 0.8}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.5, 0., 0.5}},
       {{0.44, 0., 0.56}, {0.35, 0.09, 0.56}, {0.35, 0., 0.65}},
       {{0.368, 0., 0.632}, {0.359, 0.027, 0.614}, {0.395, 0., 0.605}},
       {{0.3896, 0., 0.6104}, {0.3815, 0.0081, 0.6104}, {0.3815, 0., 0.6185}},
       {{0.38312, 0., 0.61688}, {0.38231, 0.00243, 0.61526}, {0.38555, 0., 0.61445}}}    *)
```

In the same way you can use [`FixedPointList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html), which keeps going until the result no longer changes (to within machine precision, or an arbitrary convergence goal you can set):

```
f = FixedPointList[m . # &, IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[m]]]
(*    {{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
       {{0.2, 0., 0.8}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.5, 0., 0.5}},
       {{0.44, 0., 0.56}, {0.35, 0.09, 0.56}, {0.35, 0., 0.65}},
       {{0.368, 0., 0.632}, {0.359, 0.027, 0.614}, {0.395, 0., 0.605}},
       {{0.3896, 0., 0.6104}, {0.3815, 0.0081, 0.6104}, {0.3815, 0., 0.6185}},
       {{0.38312, 0., 0.61688}, {0.38231, 0.00243, 0.61526}, {0.38555, 0., 0.61445}},
       ...
       {{0.384615, 0., 0.615385}, {0.384615, 0., 0.615385}, {0.384615, 0., 0.615385}}}    *)
```

quickly reaching the asymptote
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{5}{13} & 0 & \frac{8}{13} \\
 \frac{5}{13} & 0 & \frac{8}{13} \\
 \frac{5}{13} & 0 & \frac{8}{13} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Looking at the approach to the asymptote for a specific element, for example the element (2,1):

```
ListPlot[f[[All, 2, 1]]]
```

[image]